# Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

was getting the warning message ([image: attached image]) in the below code using react.js. I checked answers on the stackoverflow and tried to remove the warning message but it didn't help.
Made a separate example with similar functionality in a static page and it is working fine. But, this code is throwing warning message. How to remove this warning message ?

```
<tbody>
      {list.map(function(value){
             return(<tr className="gradeA" role="row">
                        <td className="sorting_1">{ value.id }</td>
                        <td>{value.name}</td>                          
                        <td>{value.location}</td>
                     </tr>);                                        
            })
        }       
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add a unique key to the returned component from map. In your map function receive define another parameter as key and for each `tr` that you return just add `key={key}` as a prop.

```
<tbody>
      {list.map(function(value, key){
             return(<tr className="gradeA" role="row" key={key}>
                        <td className="sorting_1">{ value.id }</td>
                        <td>{value.name}</td>                          
                        <td>{value.location}</td>
                     </tr>);                                        
            })
        }       
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamKhatri, was adding the same in the wrong place that is why was not able to remove the warning message. It worked now.

Comment: No problem, Happy to help :)